# Pandas to_numeric doesn't work with a numpy value inside series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to convert pandas Series into numeric series with `pd.to_numeric`. When a value can't be converted into a numeric value I'm expecting to have a `NaN` instead, so I use `errors="coerce"`.

I tried many weird inputs to make sure that users of my package will always have a numeric series whatever the series they provide. But I run into an issue when one value is a numpy array with one element.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np

>>> s = pd.Series([3, np.array(2.1)])

>>> pd.to_numeric(s, errors="coerce")
0      3
1    2.1
dtype: object
```

I know this is a strange kind of input, but I was expecting the dtype to become float instead of object (whatever if `np.array(2.1)` becomes `2.1` or `NaN`, as long as the series is numeric). Yet, here, the series dtype stays as `object`.

Note that it works correctly when the value can be converted into an int:

```py
>>> s = pd.Series([3, np.array(2.)])

>>> pd.to_numeric(s, errors="coerce")
0    3
1    2
dtype: int64
```

And it also works as expected when there is no np.array involved:

```py
>>> s = pd.Series([3., 2.2])

>>> pd.to_numeric(s, errors="coerce")
0    3.0
1    2.2
dtype: float64
```

I'm on python 3.9.7, pandas 1.3.4, numpy 1.21.4.

Comment: If your coercing to numeric anyway, why not just chain on `.astype` to standardise the dtypes. eg: `pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').astype(float)`

Comment: @ChrisAdams I guess he could, but the documentation clearly says `The default return dtype is float64 or int64`. Looks like a massive bug rather than expected behaviour to me. Was able to reproduce everythin on `Python 3.10.2`.

Comment: @ChrisAdams it does not work when there is a value that is not numeric, for instance a string. Consider `s = pd.Series([3, np.array(2.1), "a"])`, your code will crash, but I want to receive a series with (3., 2.1, NaN) or (3, NaN, NaN)